# How to read a .txt file and compare it to user input, to see if it matches in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read a .txt file and see if the user input provided (a barcode) is found in the file, if it isn't I want to tell them and then not include it in the receipt file (which'll be outputted at the end).

(Product is an array [barcode (String), quantity (String)]

```
  while line = file.gets
  line = line.split(",")
  products.each do |product|
  if line[0] != product[0]
    puts "Your item #{product[0]} could not be found in the stockfile. It will not be included in the receipt."
  end
  if line[0] == product[0] 
    receipt << [line[0],line[1],line[2]]
  end
```

Stockfile:

```
12636723,BenQ XL2411Z Monitor,29.99

12345670,Razer Deathadder Mouse,4.49

77766236,Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Laptop,65.00
```

Realised now that logic is flawed, and that if I were to do the above it'd print out not found a bunch of times. I don't know if I can ask for help with logic.

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Can you show us the values of products and sample values of lines.  In particular, what are the comma separated values?

Comment: I think there are errors in your logic.  Can you think it through in plain English?  I think if you do you will be able to see the problem.  It doesn't hurt to use a rubber duck too. :)  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reïnvent the wheel, the csv gem is made for reading such files, I do it here from the DATA portion of the file so that you can run this sample.
Products could be a struct or class, for shortness I use a Hash here.

```
require "csv"

products = [{name: 'milk', barcode: 1},{name: 'butter',barcode: 2},{name: 'flour', barcode: 3}]
receipt  = []

stock = File.read('stock.csv', :col_sep => ",", :headers => true)
stock = CSV.parse(DATA, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true)
products.each do |product|
  if stock.find {|row| row['Name'] == product[:name]}
    receipt << product.to_a
  else
    puts "Your item #{product[:name]} could not be found in the stockfile. It will not be included in the receipt."
  end
end
__END__
   Name, Quantifier, Amount
milk, liter, 2
butter, gram, 250
```

Which gives

```
# Your item flour could not be found in the stockfile. It will not be included in the receipt.
# receipt: #[[[:name, "milk"], [:barcode, 1]], [[:name, "butter"], [:barcode, 2]]]
```